# Get the datasource of current tab in an advanced banded gridview

Tags: c#, advanceddatagrid

I have an advanced banded gridview inside a usercontrol which has different tab pages inside it.

I'm trying to find the specific datasource/datatable which is currently displaying.The following both return a table but it returns the same table irrespectively on which tab page I currently have selected.

```
   ((GridView) sender).DataSource;
   ((GridView) sender).DataController.ListSource;
```

The closest I could get was using a masterRowExpanded event and doing the following inside it:

```
((GridView) sender).GetRelationName(e.RowHandle,e.RelationIndex)
```

and this returned the name of the tab page I was currently on. Any ideas on how to retrieve the source would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a while I managed to get it, inside the masterRowExpanded event I used:

```
GridView gv = sender as GridView;
AdvBandedGridView abgv = (AdvBandedGridView)(gv.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle,RelationIndex));
```

Then the advanced banded gridview had the datasource I was looking for.